# Long straight cracks in the ceiling

Tags: ceiling, crack

In several places in the ceiling of my 1986-built bungalow, there are long straight cracks running along the ceiling.

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

- What's causing them?
- Should I be concerned?
- How can I stop it from increasing?
- How can I repair the damage already done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
What's causing them?
```

The building settling.

```
Should I be concerned?
```

Not really.

```
How can I stop it from increasing?
```

You can't, but improper climate control (swings in temperature and humidity levels throughout the house) will make it worse.

```
How can I repair the damage already done?
```

I'd use fiberglass tape and joint compound (chemically setting plaster; not water soluble top coat). The non-textured ceiling would be easy. The textured one needs to be repaired in the same way and then re-textured or the entire ceiling completely de-textured with a skim coat.

I'm guessing it was originally textured with a [textured roller](https://www.google.com/search?q=textured%20roller&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

---

Another option is to caulk and paint it every time it redevelops. It's definitely worth a shot at this easy method, to see how long you can get away with just a coat of paint. You might want to widen the crack (with a [painter's tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=painter%20tool&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=painter%27s%20tool); a 5in1) so that it fills with paint/caulk and doesn't just make a bridge over the gap (that would crack again guaranteed, very soon).

Comment: I'm looking up at a similar crack right now; I've been trying to decide whether to just fix it or put in a coffered ceiling.

Comment: @keshlam I've used [decorative purlins](https://www.google.com/search?q=perlin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=decorative+purlin) on long cracks that just wouldn't give up. *Trim for the win!*